Galerkin scheme in $H^s_0(G)\subset L^2(G)\subset H^{-s}(G)$ ($s>0$)
What basis functions are usually choosen if one attempts to conduct a Galerkin finite element method given an evolution triplet $H^s_0(G)\subset L^2(G)\subset H^{-s}(G)$. Where $G$ is a sufficiently regular and bounded domain. Here $s>0$, but not an integer.

Check wavelet basis, or multiscale analysis.

Are their specific ones being orthogonal in $L^2$ and $H^s_0$?

I believe so. At least on Rn they can be made orthogonal. If not orthogonal on domain, some almost orthogonality still holds.
